# How to memoize each element in an Array.map() in React? (with useMemo)

Tags: reactjs, jsx, react-usememo

I have the following element:

```
<p>{user.name}</p>
```

I can memoize it by doing:

```
useMemo(() => (
  <p>{user.name}</p>
), [user]);
```

Now, let's say I have the following code:

```
users.map((user) => (
   <p>{user.name}</p>
));
```

How can I memoize each element of the array so that only that element rerenders when a change happens (and not the whole array)?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Does useMemo hooks in React.js also memoizes object reference as well?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69075875/does-usememo-hooks-in-react-js-also-memoizes-object-reference-as-well)

Comment: Hi! No, please read the question description more carefully.

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is a possible use case for [useCallback](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecallback).

```
const renderUser = useCallback((user) => (
  <p>{user.name}<p>
), []);

const users = users.map(renderUser);
```

You could be over-thinking things a bit, but it could also be this example that is making it hard to determine the *why* of this question, though.

The thing you're trying to memoize is, in its simplest form, a functional component with a single prop called `name`. Why not just use it like that?

```
export const UserName = ({ name }) => (<p>{name}<p>)
```

And if there's no value from doing that, why not just render the result in line where it's needed like your non-memoized example?

```js
users.map((user) => (
   <p>{user.name}</p>
));
```

Unless there's some heavy calculation happening in the JSX template of your map function OR the fn component(s) used in that mapping, I don't think you stand to benefit much from memoizing something like this.